# Como tratar uma Exception de um http Request em Asp Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core

Olá, tenho uma aplicação em *ASP.net* *MVC* que está fazendo uma requisição `http` através de uma porta de conexão que fica disponível por meio de um serviço, cujo qual está sendo executado no servidor. O `controller` chama o método e manda a resposta para a `view`.

Quando derrubo este serviço e executo a aplicação, ela gera as exceções:
`httpRequestException`, `WebException` e `SocketException`.

Gostaria de saber uma forma de tratar essa `exception` **levando uma mensagem para o usuário de forma amigável** na minha `view`, quando por exemplo decidirmos fazer uma manutenção no servidor e a porta estiver fora do ar.

Já tentei o `Try`, porém na execução ele ignora o bloco, é como se eu nem tivesse colocado o `try` e `catch` ali.

Método que faz a conexão:

```
public static string BaseUrl
{
get
{
//Base da Api seguido pelo IP e Porta de conexão do servidor
return "http://IP:888/api/millenium!status_pedidov/pedido_venda/";
}
}

public static object GetApiResultadoPedido(string CodigoPedido)
{

//Metodo que faz requisicao a API do Millennium
string action = string.Format("listaporpedido?cod_pedidov={0}&$format=json", CodigoPedido);
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, BaseUrl + action);
//LINHA ONDE A EXCESSAO É GERADA:
HttpResponseMessage response = HttpInstance.GetHttpClientInstance().SendAsync(request).Result;
var JsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
return JsonResponse;
}
```

Comment: Consegui resolver depois de um tempo... Na verdade basta colocar um if abaixo do try e mandar um return no valor de null para que no controller vc consiga fazer a validacao e entao retornar para a view um TempData com a mensagem de erro.